# Make table row(<tr>) linked without JavaScript

Tags: html

I am currently adding non-js functions to my site as some devices are still not able to handle js oder some people shut it off to have the pages loaded more fastly(like slow connections, slow devices like old computers).

So, now I have a problem: I have a page with profiles listed in a `<table>` an want each `<tr>` to be linked to a certain profile. To put the links inside the `<td>` like `<tr><td><a>Name</a></td><td><a>Address</a></td></tr>` is imo not a good solution as I will have a lot of code and only the text will be clickable.

Also

```
<a><tr><td>Text</td></tr></a>
```

Does not work.

Is there any solution without Javascript to realize this?

Thanks in advance
Naymecliff

Comment: The only valid (non-js) links are `<a>` and form submits. As your nesting doesn't create valid HTML, you're stuck with assigning an `<a>` to each cell individually.

Comment: do you have actual issues with people form your target not supporting/using js?

Comment: I was afraid so. Thanks. The issues are clear: People like me having a very slow connection sometimes wish to be able to access a webpage without the extra ballast of jscripts. I experienced it while beeing in Tanzania and being forced to use GSM network to access the internet. Every byte counts ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m afraid it’s not possible. You can make the contents of a `td` element a link, and by HTML5 rules (as well as browser practice), you can make an entire table a link. But then intermediate level, a table row element `tr`, cannot be turned to a link in HTML.

If you make the content of each `td` a link, so that the cells of a row point to the same destination, then things work in a sense, but it’s not good usability. It would not be apparent to the user what’s going, since nothing in the appearance shows that the cells of a row are really meant to be *one* link. Besides, as they are separate links, tabbing becomes awkward.

Depending on the content and nature of the table, perhaps you can choose one column as “primary” in a sense (perhaps with data such as a caption or title, something that might be regarded as row headers), and use ` ... for cells in that column only.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. I will define a "primary" column, then. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to create an html anchor?

```
<a href="#BLA">BBBB</a>

<a name="BLA"></a>
```

Content here.

Comment: Can still be done: <a href="newpage.html#BLA">BBBB</a> in calling page.

In newpage.html
<a name="BLA"></a>

Answer (score 0):

You **can** actually do this without javascript AND without duplicating your link dozens/hundreds or thousands of times unnecessarily. It depends a little on what browsers you are supporting, and specifically what CSS they support, but if like most modern ones they can handle position:absolute and td:first-child, then here is what I came up with for a similar issue:

Put the link in the first column:

```
<table class="search_results">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Some text</a></td>
        <td>more text</td>
        <td>more text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is perfectly fine markup, so your only real issue is getting that link to span the width of your table. I did it like this using pretty standard CSS:

```
table.search_results a {position:absolute;display:block;width:98%;}
```

Change the width to whatever you want and in principle you are done and dusted. So that is all relatively easy, however if you, like me, have a fluid/responsive layout, and also some standard styling on your links plus some padding on your tables, you are going to need these rules (copied necessary from above and added extra).

```
table.search_results td:first-child {padding:0;}
table.search_results a {position:absolute;display:block;width:98%;max-width:1272px;font-weight:normal;color:#000;padding:.5em;}
table.search_results a:hover {background:none;}
table.search_results tr:hover {border-color:#25505b;background:#b5d6dd;}
```

To explain:
The first rule removes all padding on my first td ONLY. By default the padding on my td is .5em.
The second rule adds the same padding back on the link, otherwise you end up with misaligned cell contents. It also corrects a few standard styles I have on my a to ensure the columns all look the same. You could do this the other way around too (add the link styles to your td). 
With the last two rules I get rid of the default hover effect on my links, then put it on the tr for any tables with the right class.

This works in the browsers I care about, but you should of course test in those you care about :) Hope I help save someone some minutes with this writeup!